# dividing image into non-overlapping and overlapping blocks

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have an image of 256*256.I have to divide the image into sub blocks of size W * W,where W=3,4,.....27 according to the given overlapping rules below:
    if W<8  thn no overlapping of blocks
    if 8<=W<=13  thn 50% overlapping of blocks
    if W>13    thn 75% overlapping of blocks
    how to implement it in  matlab,particularly in 2nd and in 3rd rule

Answer (score 2):

The quickest and simplest way of achieving something like what you're interested in is as follows:

```
function blocks = DivideImage(im, W)

if W <= 7
    step = W;
elseif W <= 13
    step = round(0.25 * W);
else
    step = round(0.125 * W);
end

startPos = 0:step:size(im,1)-W;

blocks = cell(numel(startPos), numel(startPos));
for i = 1:numel(startPos)
    for j = 1:numel(startPos)
        blocks{i,j} = im(startPos(i)+(1:W), startPos(j)+(1:W));
    end
end
```

Note that when `W` doesn't divide exactly into `size(im,1)` then it will drop some of the points from the right and bottom edges, so you will want to look again at how it's setting the values of `startPos`.